# Set page name of navigator page objects

Tags: onsen-ui

getCurrentPage() and getPages() return page objects with a "name" property. This is the same as the page URL of my template (ie. page2.html). How can I set the name?

Comment: The name of page object means page URL. Why do you want to set the name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute "name". eg:

```
<ons-page name="myPage">
...
</ons-page>
```